# Second thread after 2 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, random, jlabel

My function draws three random numbers and depending on this number sets appropriate icons for JLabel's (one, two, three). I need to change this icons after 2 seconds.

```
    public void random() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    num1 = rand.nextInt(3);
    num2 = rand.nextInt(3);
    num3 = rand.nextInt(3);   

    if (num1==0){
        one.setIcon(icon7);
    }
    if (num1==1){
        one.setIcon(icon8);
    }
    if (num1==2){
        one.setIcon(icon9);
    }

    if (num2==0){
        two.setIcon(icon7);
    }
    if (num2==1){
        two.setIcon(icon8);
    }
    if (num2==2){
        two.setIcon(icon9);
    }  

    if (num3==0){
        three.setIcon(icon7);
    }
    if (num3==1){
        three.setIcon(icon8);
    }
    if (num3==2){
        three.setIcon(icon9);
    }}
```

and after 2 seconds I want to change the icons like this:

```
    one.setIcon(icon10);
    two.setIcon(icon10);
    three.setIcon(icon10);
```

I have no idea, how to do this, please help me:)

Answer (score 3):

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(2000, null);
ActionListener listener = new ActionListsner() {

@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        one.setIcon(icon10);
        two.setIcon(icon10);
        three.setIcon(icon10);
 }
};
timer.addActionListener(listener);
timer.start();
```

This code call the setIcon function every 2 seconds but if you want to call only for 1 or two times you can put condition under actionPerformed function... hope it help you!..

Comment: If you want to call exactly one time you set say `timer.setRepeats(false);` right after its creation.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code a bit first:

```
private static final Random rand = new Random();

//somewhere on init.
final JLabel[] myLabels = new JLabel[3];
for(int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; ++i) {
    myLabels[i] = new JLabel();
    //add to panel or whatever.
}

private void setIcon(final int value, final JLabel label) {
    switch(value) {
        case 0:
            label.setIcon(icon7);
            break;
        case 1:
            label.setIcon(icon8);
            break;
        case 2:
            label.setIcon(icon9);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be between 0 and 2.");
    }
}

public void random() {
    for(int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; ++i) {
        setLabel(rand.nextInt(3), myLabels[i]);
    }
    scheduleReset();
}
```

I would then write the `scheduleReset` method to use a non-repeating swing `Timer`.

```
public void scheduleReset() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2), new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae) {
            resetIcons();
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}

public void resetIcons() {
    for(int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; ++i) {
        myLabels[i].setIcon(icon10);
    }
}
```